# How to generate XML sitemap for one category in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Am looking for a way to generate XML sitemap for one single category in my Magento 2 store. I already know how to generate the XML sitemap for the entire store but I need to split the sitemaps into categories for easier tracking.

Comment: You can check this reference link. Where you need to change the category id. https://www.webcreta.com/how-to-generate-a-category-specific-sitemap-in-magento-2/

Comment: @JitendraPatel I already tried this it doesnt generate the sitemaps

Comment: Where can I get the SitemapGenerator file required @JitendraPatel